# RSolr::Error::Http: RSolr::Error::Http - 400 Bad Request error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sunspot, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

I'm trying to index rich documents but I'm facing some issues. I'm following this link:

http://cbpowell.wordpress.com/2012/09/18/indexing-rich-documents-with-rails-sunspot-solr-sunspot-cell-and-carrierwave-cookbook-style/

```
$rake sunspot:reindex

rake aborted!

RSolr::Error::Http: RSolr::Error::Http - 400 Bad Request

Error: {'responseHeader'=>{'status'=>400,'QTime'=>29},'error'=>{'msg'=>'undefined field type','code'=>400}}

Request Data: "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><delete><query>type:Article</query></delete>"
```

Note: Solr we are configured manually (not inside application)

http://archive.apache.org/dist/lucene/solr/4.7.0/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using solr 4.7.0 please pay attention to tika-core-x.x.jar and tika-parser-x.x.jar files. [sunspot_cell_jars](https://github.com/mrcsparker/sunspot_cell_jars) gem includes outdated version for both of them (check this page www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/t/tika.htm to find correct version for yours configuration)

Also you can try use updated [sunspot_cell](https://github.com/brovikov/sunspot_cell) gem